# Как соединить MySQL к сервлету?

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, servlet

```
@WebServlet(name = "ServletBlog", urlPatterns = "/posts")
public class Servlets extends HttpServlet {
{ 
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3300/db","root","root");
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
         ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM db")) {

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("DB CONNECT ERROR");
    }
```

в Classpath загрузил driver(в intellij idea(mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar)) но все равно пишет "DB CONNECT ERROR"

пример exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3300/db
```

Comment: Вопрос задан неверно: MySQL и сервлет вы "соединили", но реальная проблема в том, что ваш код не видит необходимый класс. Возможно, нужно указать в вашем проекте зависимость от внешней библиотеки: http://nixmash.com/java/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-fix-in-intellij-idea/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ:

1.If you're running inside an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, you have to add the JAR to a library.

2.IF you're running in a command shell, use the -p option for javac.exe when you compile and java.exe when you run.

3.If you're using it in a web app, you can start by putting it in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your WAR file. If you're using a servlet/JSP engine like Tomcat 6, put it in the Tomcat /lib directory.

мне помогло пункт 3.